# Bibliography contents page numbering - LaTeX

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I have added a bibliography to my document in LaTeX which is 2 1/2 pages long. In the contents page the page number for the Bibliography is recorded as the final page of the bibliography instead of the first. So it starts on page 56 and ends on page 58, with the contents page displaying page 58.

This is where the bibliography is added.

```
\bibliography{SFBib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
```

And the contents page:

```
\tableofcontents
```

Could anyone suggest how to display the correct page numbering on the contents page?

Comment: I think you've got the order wrong for `\bibliography{SFBib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}`. Try putting the `\addcontentsline`. (not 100% sure, but give that a try)

Comment: I have put the \addcontentsline first and a \clearpage before that as it was showing the previous page to the bibliography instead. Seems to work now though, thanks.

Comment: Ah, cool. Annoying that you need a \clearpage, but I think that is due to the nature of the bibliography. I posted this as an answer so that others know. If it works for you, click that it worked.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got the order wrong for

```
\bibliography{SFBib} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
```

Try putting the

```
\addcontentsline
```

first and a

```
 \clearpage
```

before that.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your post.

Comment: So, in essence, use `\clearpage\addcontentsline...`.